# Retrieve specific depth in k shorest path query

Tags: shortest-path, arangodb, graphdb, aql

I am applying this query for example

```
FOR path 
  IN ANY K_SHORTEST_PATHS  
  'person/27' TO 'person/36'    
  case_item, relationship, transaction_link, passenger, is_on_watchlist, georelation, communication   
  RETURN path
```

this query returns all the paths with different depth
i want to give in min and max depth to return only paths in this specific range

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/tutorial-traversal.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want to find the shortest paths, or paths with minimum and maximum depth.  To limit your query to a certain max depth you switch from `K_SHORTEST_PATHS` to `K_PATHS` and add the limitation after the `IN` (replace MAX with your desired depth):

```
FOR path
  IN 1..MAX ANY K_PATHS
  person/27' TO 'person/36'    
  case_item, relationship, transaction_link, passenger, is_on_watchlist, georelation, communication   
  RETURN path
```